# Create a div separately to each bottom-up data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

I want to create a div for each bottom-up and I'm going to give you a few data that I think you might need.

```js
// data is the response from an AJAX request:
var data = [{"title":"Https test ","content":"https://endorfintr.tk","sharer":"EndorfinTR"},{"title":"a","content":"ÇAYLARRRRR","sharer":"DataBaseTester","editer":"EndorfinTR"},{"title":"Bakım sürecinin %75i bitti! ","content":"Bakım sürecinin %75inden fazlasına girmis bulunmaktayız, bu süreçte adminleri ve siteyi kökten etkileyecek bir sürü ekleme yapıldı. Örneğin Post ekleme, post silme benzeri şeyler eklendi. /n Bakım sürecinin bitiminde görüşmek üzere ","sharer":"EndorfinTR","editer":"EndorfinTR"},{"title":"Blog Websitesine Kısa Bir Ara","content":"Merhabalar ben EndorfinTR, websiteye biraz ara vereceğim. Çünkü hostumuzda bir kaç arıza çıktı.","sharer":"EndorfinTR"},{"title":"Rus - Ukrayna savaşı Müzakereleri","content":"Rus - Ukrayna savaşı tarafları Belarus sınırında müzakere yapacak, sonuçlar için beklemeyi unutmayın!","sharer":"ThesseliaTR"},{"title":"Merhabaaa","content":"Selam","sharer":"ThesseliaTR","date":"09 Mart Çarşamba 2022, 21:00"}]

// Inside the AJAX callback
$(".postsMain").empty();

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  var alt = $("<div>", {
    class: "postsAlt"
  }).appendTo(".postsMain");
  $("<p>").html(item.title).appendTo(alt);
});
```

```html
<div class="postsMain"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by 'bottom-up data' you mean that you want to loop through the data in reverse order. The quick way to do this would be to use `reverse()` on the `data` array before you iterate through it.

Note in this example that I used `map()` to build the HTML to make the code more succinct:

```js
$(function() {
  let data = [{"title":"Https test ","content":"https://endorfintr.tk","sharer":"EndorfinTR"},{"title":"a","content":"ÇAYLARRRRR","sharer":"DataBaseTester","editer":"EndorfinTR"},{"title":"Bakım sürecinin %75i bitti! ","content":"Bakım sürecinin %75inden fazlasına girmis bulunmaktayız, bu süreçte adminleri ve siteyi kökten etkileyecek bir sürü ekleme yapıldı. Örneğin Post ekleme, post silme benzeri şeyler eklendi. /n Bakım sürecinin bitiminde görüşmek üzere ","sharer":"EndorfinTR","editer":"EndorfinTR"},{"title":"Blog Websitesine Kısa Bir Ara","content":"Merhabalar ben EndorfinTR, websiteye biraz ara vereceğim. Çünkü hostumuzda bir kaç arıza çıktı.","sharer":"EndorfinTR"},{"title":"Rus - Ukrayna savaşı Müzakereleri","content":"Rus - Ukrayna savaşı tarafları Belarus sınırında müzakere yapacak, sonuçlar için beklemeyi unutmayın!","sharer":"ThesseliaTR"},{"title":"Merhabaaa","content":"Selam","sharer":"ThesseliaTR","date":"09 Mart Çarşamba 2022, 21:00"}]
  
  // inside AJAX callback...
  let html = data.reverse().map(o => `<div class="postsAlt"><p>${o.title}</p></div>`);
  $('.postsMain').html(html);
});
```

```html
<div class="postsMain"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Alternatively you could use a `for` loop with a negative step:

```js
$(function() {
  let data = [{"title":"Https test ","content":"https://endorfintr.tk","sharer":"EndorfinTR"},{"title":"a","content":"ÇAYLARRRRR","sharer":"DataBaseTester","editer":"EndorfinTR"},{"title":"Bakım sürecinin %75i bitti! ","content":"Bakım sürecinin %75inden fazlasına girmis bulunmaktayız, bu süreçte adminleri ve siteyi kökten etkileyecek bir sürü ekleme yapıldı. Örneğin Post ekleme, post silme benzeri şeyler eklendi. /n Bakım sürecinin bitiminde görüşmek üzere ","sharer":"EndorfinTR","editer":"EndorfinTR"},{"title":"Blog Websitesine Kısa Bir Ara","content":"Merhabalar ben EndorfinTR, websiteye biraz ara vereceğim. Çünkü hostumuzda bir kaç arıza çıktı.","sharer":"EndorfinTR"},{"title":"Rus - Ukrayna savaşı Müzakereleri","content":"Rus - Ukrayna savaşı tarafları Belarus sınırında müzakere yapacak, sonuçlar için beklemeyi unutmayın!","sharer":"ThesseliaTR"},{"title":"Merhabaaa","content":"Selam","sharer":"ThesseliaTR","date":"09 Mart Çarşamba 2022, 21:00"}]
  
  // inside AJAX callback...
  let html = '';
  for (let i = data.length; i--; i >= 0) {
    html += `<div class="postsAlt"><p>${data[i].title}</p></div>`;
  }
  $('.postsMain').html(html);
});
```

```html
<div class="postsMain"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In both cases the important point to note is that you should build the HTML string in the loop and only append the content to the DOM in ***one operation***. This is because accessing the DOM is one of the slowest things JS can do, so you should look to avoid it as much as possible - especially when working in a loop.

Comment: What I meant by 'bottom-up data' was that it created a separate div for each data, but each div was top to bottom.

Comment: In that case I have no idea what your question is asking, because your code is already doing that. You can see it working in the snippet I edited in to your question. If it's not working for you then you may have an error in your AJAX logic. Check the console for errors.